# Regex one-liner for splitting string at nth character where n is a variable length

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax

I've found a few similar questions, but none of them are clean one-liners, which I feel should be possible.  I want to split a string at the last instance of specific character (in my case `.`).

```
var img = $('body').attr('data-bg-img-url'); // the string http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img.jpg
var finalChar = img.split( img.split(/[.]+/).length-1 ); // returns int 3 in above string example
var dynamicRegex = '/[.$`finalChar`]/';
```

I know I'm breaking some rules here, wondering if someone smarter than me knows the correct way to put that together and compress it?

**EDIT** - The end goal here is to split and store `http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img` and `.jpg` as separate strings.

Comment: What is your end-game here?

Comment: `str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('.')); // .jpg` ;)

Comment: end goal is to split and store both the `http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img` and `.jpg` as separate variables.

Comment: `/./` matches any character, `/\./` matches a dot.

Comment: If you need extension for something like validation or grabbing images from external sites, then go for mimetype detection based on actual file contents. It will be much more reliable.

Comment: Nah - this is dynamic generation of a large background image being served responsively.  So, basically `http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img.jpg` will be split and then converted to either `http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img-2560x1440.jpg` or `http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img-1680x1050.jpg`.  This is handled on page load and then the images are injected in the DOM dynamically.  Image size breakpoints are a known variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex, `.*` is greedy, meaning it will match as much as possible.  Therefore, if you want to match up to the last `.`, you could do:

```
/^.*\./
```

And from the looks, you are trying to get the file extension, so you would want to add capture:

```
var result = /^.*\.(.*)$/.exec( str );
var extension = result[1];
```

And for both parts:

```
var result = /^(.*)\.(.*)$/.exec( str );
var path = result[1];
var extension = result[2];
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually need to store both `http://sub.foo.com/img/my-img` and `.jpg` as separate vars.

Comment: Thanks Lucas - that's what I was looking for... just used `exec()` the other day and I knew it should be simple and was fuzzy on the proper function for this, your answer is right on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lastIndexOf() method on the period and then use the substring method to obtain the first and second string. The split() method is better used in a foreach scenario where you want to split at all instances. Substring is preferable for these types of cases where you are breaking at a single instance of the string.